# how to create a class that the instance variables like rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know that a class can be created as

```rb
class User
  attr_reader :id, :name, :email
  def initialize(id, name, email)
    @id = id
    @name = name
    @email = email 
  end
end
user = User.new(1, "my_name", "my_email")
user.inspect   '#<User:0x401b4924 @id=1, @name="my_name", @email="my_email">
```

is it possible to create object just like rails active record relation below?

```rb
user = User.new(1, "my_name", "my_email")
user.inspect   '#<User:0x401b4924 id: 1, name: "my_name", email: "my_email">
```

Comment: Sure change your inspect method [just like rails does](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Core/inspect)

Comment: @engineersmnky, thank you. Perfect, this is the answer I'm looking for. It is about inspection only.